# problem on electronics involving integration and combined probability function.

Tags: integration, probability-distributions

Our professor in electronics gave us [eq. 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E86ds.jpg) to evaluate. I found this pdf on Electronics 2 that has the answer which is eq. 2. I tried doing it but never got to the solution. If someone could give me an idea on how to get close to the solution. I am just having trouble with the integral.

Comment: this is the complementary error function, this cannot be expresed by elementary means.

Comment: moreover, from the image you share, eq 1 is having as a codition something, and eq 2 is changing the condition i.e. eq2 is not the result of eq 1.